# Performance issues when running 2D examples locally

Tags: windows, performance, rust, webassembly

I'm compiling and running the 2D examples of [nphysics](https://www.nphysics.org/) on Windows 10 like so.

```
PS C:\projects> git clone --branch v0.16.1 https://github.com/dimforge/nphysics.git

PS C:\projects> cd nphysics

PS C:\projects\nphysics> rustc --version
rustc 1.48.0 (7eac88abb 2020-11-16)

PS C:\projects\nphysics> cargo version
cargo 1.48.0 (65cbdd2dc 2020-10-14)

cargo run --release --bin all_examples2
```

However, these examples are actually running slower than their WASM WebGL counterparts in the browser.

https://www.nphysics.org/all_examples2/

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong/overlooking?

[Video of the issue](https://gofile.io/d/E97Hz7)

Comment: Assuming you're just running examples, then it does indeed sound odd that a WASM WebGL version would perform better than a Vulkan/OpenGL version. You'll more likely receive an answer to your issue, if you submit an issue to nphysics' [issue tracker](https://github.com/dimforge/nphysics/issues)

Comment: Mobile devices usually default to using the integrated GPU. If you are running this on, say, a laptop you'd be comparing a release build running on the integrated chip with whatever your browser requests. The latter usually requests a dedicated GPU if available.

Comment: I've added a better quality video to the link please check again. @IInspectable I've tried on both a desktop and laptop computer both have discrete gpus.

Comment: Having a discrete GPU is required but not sufficient to run on a discrete GPU. You'll need to verify whether you are.

Comment: I think what @IInspectable means is, make sure the examples are actually using the discrete GPU, they might be configured wrong. Also have you also tried turning on LTO?